# how to put some data option key url on Highchart?

Tags: highcharts

i tried add some url on my chart bar so when it click it goes to another page
but i have no idea where i should put the option key. Please give some advice, here's my code

```
    plotOptions: {

    series: {
        cursor: 'pointer',
        point: {
            events: {
                click: function () {
                    location.href = 'https://xxxxxxxx.com/ratnik2/chart_month.php?m=' +
                        this.options.key;
                }
            }
        }
    },
    column: {
        stacking: 'normal',
        pointPadding: 0.2,
        borderWidth: 0,
        dataLabels:
        {
        enabled:true
        }
    }
},
series: [ {
    name: 'Surat Terbit',
    data: [";
    $query->execute("select month(tanggal), count(*) as jumlah
    from surat where year(tanggal)=year(now())
    and tgl_ttd is not null
    group by month(tanggal)
    order by month(tanggal) asc
    ");

    while ($row = $query->fetch()){
    $isi .= $row["jumlah"].",";
    }

  $isi .="]
  name: '',
  key: ''
  }]
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/series-point-events-click-url/

```
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        cursor: 'pointer',
        point: {
            events: {
                click: function () {
                    location.href = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/' +
                        this.options.key;
                }
            }
        }
    }
},
```